# Lambda compile behavior with local variables

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, lambda

I was curious in what ways the compiler handled lambdas declared in loops. I've had a few cases where I've declared lambdas inline so that I can use variables local to the calling method within the lambda.  I've included two examples below.

Will the compiler create N delegates for a lambda within a loop? What (and which) optimizations can the compiler make in such cases? Additionally, [MSDN mentions to use lambdas over anonymous functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx), but doesn't go into depth as to why. So, why?


**Example 1:**

```
public static class MethodPlayground1
{
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            int methodLocal1 = i;
            string methodLocal2 = i.ToString();
            KeyValuePair<int, string> methodLocal3 = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, i.ToString());
            // Case A
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
            {
                int threadLocal1 = methodLocal1 + 1;
                string threadLocal2 = methodLocal2 + " o'clock";
                int threadLocal3 = methodLocal3.Key + 2;
                string threadLocal4 = methodLocal3.Value + " oranges";
            });
            // Case B
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
            {
                int threadLocal1 = methodLocal1 + 1;
                string threadLocal2 = methodLocal2 + " o'clock";
                int threadLocal3 = methodLocal3.Key + 2;
                string threadLocal4 = methodLocal3.Value + " oranges";
            });
            // Case C
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
            {
                int threadLocal1 = methodLocal1 + 1;
                string threadLocal2 = methodLocal2 + " o'clock";
                int threadLocal3 = methodLocal3.Key + 2;
                string threadLocal4 = methodLocal3.Value + " oranges";
            });
            // Case D
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
            {
                int threadLocal1 = methodLocal1 + 1;
                string threadLocal2 = methodLocal2 + " o'clock";
                int threadLocal3 = methodLocal3.Key + 2;
                string threadLocal4 = methodLocal3.Value + " oranges";
            });
            // Case E
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncMethod, new object[] { methodLocal1, methodLocal2, methodLocal3 });
        }
    }
    private static void AsyncMethod(object state)
    {
        object[] methodArgs = (object[])state;
        int methodArg1 = (int)methodArgs[0];
        string methodArg2 = (string)methodArgs[1];
        KeyValuePair<int, string> methodArg3 = (KeyValuePair<int, string>)methodArgs[2];

        int threadLocal1 = methodArg1 + 1;
        string threadLocal2 = methodArg2 + " o'clock";
        int threadLocal3 = methodArg3.Key + 2;
        string threadLocal4 = methodArg3.Value + " oranges";
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
public static class MethodPlayground2
{
    private static int PriorityNumber;
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        List<int> testList = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            // Case A
            testList.Sort((i1, i2) =>
            {
                if ((i1 == i) || (i2 == i))
                {
                    if (i1 == i2) return 0;
                    else if (i1 == i) return -1;
                    else return 1;
                }
                else return i1.CompareTo(i2);
            });
            // Case B
            testList.Sort(delegate(int i1, int i2)
            {
                if ((i1 == i) || (i2 == i))
                {
                    if (i1 == i2) return 0;
                    else if (i1 == i) return -1;
                    else return 1;
                }
                else return i1.CompareTo(i2);
            });
            PriorityNumber = i;
            // Case C
            testList.Sort(IntCompareWithPriority1);
            // Case D
            testList.Sort(IntCompareWithPriority2);
            // Case E
            testList.Sort(IntCompareWithPriority3);
        }
    }
    private static Comparison<int> IntCompareWithPriority1 = (i1, i2) =>
    {
        if ((i1 == PriorityNumber) || (i2 == PriorityNumber))
        {
            if (i1 == i2) return 0;
            else if (i1 == PriorityNumber) return -1;
            else return 1;
        }
        else return i1.CompareTo(i2);
    };
    private static Comparison<int> IntCompareWithPriority2 = delegate(int i1, int i2)
    {
        if ((i1 == PriorityNumber) || (i2 == PriorityNumber))
        {
            if (i1 == i2) return 0;
            else if (i1 == PriorityNumber) return -1;
            else return 1;
        }
        else return i1.CompareTo(i2);
    };
    private static int IntCompareWithPriority3(int i1, int i2)
    {
        if ((i1 == PriorityNumber) || (i2 == PriorityNumber))
        {
            if (i1 == i2) return 0;
            else if (i1 == PriorityNumber) return -1;
            else return 1;
        }
        else return i1.CompareTo(i2);
    }
}
```

It seems that I'm not accomplishing much in Example 1. Using lambdas is a little easier to write, since I don't have to do any casting. However, any of the method local variables that I want to pass into the delegate I can do so through the `object state` parameter.

In Example 2, it seems much cleaner to use the method local variables, as opposed to setting a static variable, especially since the static variable implementation doesn't seem it would be thread-safe.


I'm looking for an answer as to the best use of lambda functions and which of the Cases are best optimized in each of the Examples above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case, the only benefit that you get using lambdas/anonymous methods over a method is that you avoid the casting between `object` and the type that you want to use; if you are relying heavily on value-types, then you'll incur boxing every time that method (with a parameter of type `object`) is called.

Normally, that's not a big deal, but if your dealing with really high counts of the callback, it can start having an impact.

Lambdas (that are not [`Expression<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx))/anonymous methods and a delegate that points to a method are no different; the C# compiler compiles the lambda/anonymous function into a method on a class that your code doesn't see and then wires the delegate up to *that*.

The [MSDN page you link to](http://lambda%20expressions%20supersede%20anonymous%20methods%20as%20the%20preferred%20way%20to%20write%20inline%20code) states (emphasis mine):

> lambda expressions supersede anonymous methods as the preferred way to write **inline code**

Because they mention "inline code", lambdas provide the most succinct way of writing code; since it's inline, most would naturally want to have the the most brief representation possible.  After all, what's more readable, this:

```
var query = myEnumerable.Where(x => x > 2);
```

Or this?

```
var query = myEnumerable.Where(delegate(x) { return x > 2; });
```

It's more typing in the second case than in the first for *the exact same thing*.  Additionally, if the method signature that took the delegate ever changed from a delegate to an `Expression<T>` (presumably, to do some analysis of the lambda for some benefit), then code that calls that with a lambda would *still* compile, while the code that uses a delegate or anonymous function would *not*.

Note, there is also only *one* method that is generated for the lambda/anonymous delegate.  It doesn't create *multiple* methods depending on where the variable is declared.  What the compiler ends up doing is creating a method with a *wider scope*.

Using your (modified) example:

```
public static void TestMethod()
{
    // Scope of the lambda starts here.

    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        // Case A
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        });
    }

    // And ends here.
 }
```

The method that the compiler creates will close *over* the loop, so that you might get repeated values for `i` (depending on when the `ThreadPool` picks up the call).

However, when you assign the variable *inside* the loop, the compiler is smart enough to know it only needs the code *inside*, like so:

```
public static void TestMethod()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        // Scope of the lambda starts here.  

        // Create copy.
        int copy = i;

        // Case A
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => {
            Console.WriteLine(copy);
        });

        // And ends here.
    }
}
```

In the above, each callback to the `ThreadPool` will print out a distinct value.

It should be noted that [in C# 5.0, there is a breaking change to this behavior for the `foreach` statement, but not the `for` statement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

*Many* developers don't understand the impact of the closure over the loop, which is the primary reason for the change.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome and very complete answer! Also, that last link is a good read.